# Not giving the correct average while calculating the Mean Absolute Percentage Error

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am analysing a forecast and a station data. During the night, I am getting negative values on the station, and zero values on the forecast data. And there are some days I am missing some data.

Keeping that in mind, I am trying to calculate the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE) in DAX within Power BI to compare my forecast values to my station data. If there is a value equal or less than a 0, or there is not any value, then do nothing. However, I am not getting the correct average for my MAPE. Here's how I am currently calculating it:

```
MAPE =
VAR Actual =
    AVERAGE ( STATION_TABLE[GHI] )
VAR Forecast =
    AVERAGE ( FORECAST_TABLE[GHI] )
VAR AbsoluteError =
    ABS ( Actual - Forecast )
RETURN
    IF (
        OR ( Actual <= 0, Forecast <= 0 ),
        BLANK (),
        DIVIDE ( AbsoluteError, Actual )
    )
```

I am then averaging the MAPE for all of my data points using the following measure:

```
MAPE_Average = AVERAGE([MAPE])
```

I made a table with the date, hour, station data, the forecast data and the MAPE result to compare the result. The MAPE is correct until it calculate the average.

| DATE | HOUR | STATION_DATA | FORECAST_DATA | MAPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 00:00 | - | - | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 01:00 | - | - | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 02:00 | - | - | - |
| ............ | ............ | ............ | ............ | ............ |
| 05/01/2023 | 10:00 | 55 | - | - |
| 05/01/2023 | 11:00 | 56 | - | - |
| 05/01/2023 | 12:00 | 89 | - | - |
| ............ | ............ | ............ | ............ | ............ |
| 07/01/2023 | 10:00 | - | 45 | - |
| 07/01/2023 | 11:00 | - | 78 | - |
| 07/01/2023 | 12:00 | - | 100 | - |
| ............ | ............ | ............ | ............ | ............ |
| 08/01/2023 | 13:00 | -5.0 | 45 | - |
| 08/01/2023 | 14:00 | -4.6 | 78 | - |
| 08/01/2023 | 15:00 | -5.1 | 100 | - |
| .......... | ............ | ............ | ............ | ............ |
| 09/01/2023 | 12:00 | 45 | 49 | 8.89% |
| 09/01/2023 | 13:00 | 56 | 51 | 8.93% |
| 09/01/2023 | 14:00 | 105 | 120 | 14.29% |
| - | - | TOTAL AVE: 300 | TOTAL AVE: 309 | TOTAL: 3.0% |

However, when I compare this value to the MAPE total calculated using other tools (such as Excel), I am getting a different average. The average on the table is the value MAPE result of the **TOTAL AVE** values at the end of the table. So, I am not getting the average of the whole column. And the measurement, which I did in apart, is giving another result which is not the same in Excel and neither the table.

Can anyone help me identify what I might be doing wrong, or suggest an alternative approach for calculating the MAPE in DAX?

Here I will add one day as example:

| DATE | HOUR | STATION_DATA | FORECAST_DATA | MAPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 00:00 | -5.21 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 01:00 | -5.24 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 02:00 | -5.17 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 03:00 | -5.22 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 04:00 | -5.07 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 05:00 | -5.43 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 06:00 | 16.94 | 15.5 | 8.52% |
| 01/01/2023 | 07:00 | 146.43 | 130 | 11.22% |
| 01/01/2023 | 08:00 | 292.26 | 323 | 10.52% |
| 01/01/2023 | 09:00 | 515.99 | 505.5 | 2.03% |
| 01/01/2023 | 10:00 | 669.63 | 663.5 | 0.92% |
| 01/01/2023 | 11:00 | 782.34 | 735 | 6.05% |
| 01/01/2023 | 12:00 | 914.03 | 761 | 16.74 |
| 01/01/2023 | 13:00 | 659.63 | 683.5 | 3.62% |
| 01/01/2023 | 14:00 | 572.60 | 491 | 14.25% |
| 01/01/2023 | 15:00 | 549.93 | 344.5 | 37.36% |
| 01/01/2023 | 16:00 | 321.52 | 219.5 | 31.73% |
| 01/01/2023 | 17:00 | 74.38 | 60 | 19.34% |
| 01/01/2023 | 18:00 | -5.40 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 19:00 | -6.28 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 20:00 | -6.76 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 21:00 | -6.47 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 22:00 | -6.28 | 0 | - |
| 01/01/2023 | 23:00 | -6.31 | 0 | - |
|  | TOTAL | 226.95 | 205.50 | 9.45% |

If we check the total average, it should be 13.52% a not 9.45% which is the MAPE between 226.95 and 205.50.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Comment: @Peter I hope it is more clear with that example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer but it can't be applied in all cases, I just create a new measure that call the measure I posted before:

```
Measure_2 = 
SUMX(
    VALUES('Fact Table_TIME'[Hour]),
    IF(
       [MAPE] > 0, [MAPE]
    )
)/12
```

The 12 is the counts of values in the column [MAPE]